# JavaScript regex replace all parts of a string except parts that contain a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's say I had the following string `Hello World` and I wanted to replace every part of it that does not contain an `o` or a space with an `x`.
Using regex, I could simply do the following:

```js
var myStr = "Hello World";
console.log(myStr.replace(/[^o ]/g, "x"));
```

Now, what if I wanted to replace all parts of a string that does not contain the string `ll` or a space for example, with an `x`?
I tried this but with no luck:

```js
// intended result: xxllx xxxxx
var myStr = "Hello World";
console.log(myStr.replace(/[^ll ]/g, "x"));
```

It seems to be interpreting the `ll` as separate characters and not a character sequence. 
How would I go about solving this with regex and using the `replace` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match and capture what you want to keep, match everything else to replace:

```js
var myStr = "Hello World";
console.log(myStr.replace(/(ll| )|[\s\S]/g, (x,y) => y || "x"));
```

Before ES6+:

```js
var myStr = "Hello World";
    console.log(myStr.replace(/(ll| )|[\s\S]/g, function (x,y) {
        return y || "x";
    })
);
```

So, `(ll| )|[\s\S]` matches and captures into Group 1 `ll` or a space, or just matches any char with `[\s\S]` (you may use `[^]` (in any JS environment) or a `.` with `/s` modifier (in ECMAScript2018+ compatible environments)) and if Group 1 matches (`y` in the above code), it is returned back. Else, replace with `x`.

Comment: Could be made a tiny bit smaller by returning `y || 'x'` instead of using a ternary operator and repeating `y`, but it's still a nice solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this pure regex solution using look-arounds:

```js
var str = 'Hello World';

var re = /(?<!l)l(?!l)|[^l ]/g;

var repl = str.replace(re, 'x');

console.log(repl);
//=> xxllx xxxxx
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!l)l(?!l)`: Match `l` if it is not followed and preceded by another `l`
- `|`; OR
- `[^l ]`: Match any character that is not `l` and not a space

[Online RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8Yi0W/1)

Comment: I know that `?!` means not followed by, but what does the `?<!` mean in regex?

Comment: `(?<!...)` is negative lookbehind assertion. It means something is not preceded from current position